# React Native Navigation through views

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigator

I have a stack navigator as followed:

```
const screens= {
LoginPage: {  
  screen: Login,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerShown: false
      },
},
RegisterPage: {
  screen: Register,
  navigationOptions: {
  headerShown: false
      },
},
DetailsPage: {
  screen: Details,
  navigationOptions: {
  headerShown: false
    },
},
ProfilePage:{
  screen: Home,
  navigationOptions:{
    headerShown: false
    },
  }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

In App.js I'm calling this. So when I launch the app I'm on the login page. Each view has their own JS file, so I navigate through JS files here. Everything works and I can reach details page with navigation, but then I have a problem.
Here is the code of my detailspage view

```
class DetailsPage extends React.Component {

render() {

    return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}}
                        **onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate('ProfilePage')}**/>                         
  </View>
);
```

}

I want to go to profilepage (written in my navigator screens) when clicking on the touchable but I have no idea how to write the navigation in OnPress to reach that view ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing wrong with the code you've written. Have you tried running it? What is the output/error?

Comment: of course, I get this
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this4.navigation.navigate')"

Comment: You were right, it was working, it's just that in my stack navigator I was calling Details with DetailsPage and Details.js contained only the component I wanted to show (<Map/> from another JS file on which I had my touchable, so the navigation props was not transmitted to that view). I changed details for Map directly and it's working :)

Comment: Kudos to you for figuring it out on your own :)